# Crystal reports not getting data from sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, crystal-reports

I am trying to use crystal reports with sqlite.
The Development enviornment is windows x64 with vs2010 x86+x64.
Crystal reports 64 bit is installed and sqlite is being used as a local assembly and not installed in the GAC.

Now if i try to use sqlite 64 bit it runs when running from vs but if i package it then it crashes trying to access the db.
If i use sqlite 32 bit everything runs fine while running from vs but when i try to package it the application itself can access sqlite db fine but the crystal reports part just keeps showing round waiting animation.

Any idea whats the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be very hard to diagnose connection problems in Crystal Report. I recommend that you try to use [ADO.NET (XML)](https://developer-content.emc.com/developer/downloads/CrystalReport_ADO_Dataset.pdf) as the way you connect to your database.